# Expand and Collapse with Slide Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I intend to have a clickable text with sliding animation. I currently have this:

**JavaScript: (`expand-collapse.js`)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide();

    $(".heading").click(function() {
        var header = $(this);

        header.next(".content").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <style>
        .heading {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/expand-collapse.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="heading">VIEW SEAT MAP (EXPAND / COLLAPSE)</div>
    <img class="content" src="images/seatmap.png" width="500" height="300" alt="seatmap">
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image]
So far, it expands and collapses as it should, but instead of having a static text that says

**VIEW SEAT MAP (EXPAND / COLLAPSE)**

all the time, I prefer it to say
**VIEW SEAT MAP (EXPAND)

VIEW SEAT MAP (COLLAPSE)**

accordingly, with only the `EXPAND` and `COLLAPSE` text being clickable like an `<a href>` (as opposed to the entire heading div). I am very new to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `a` to heading:

```
<div class="heading">VIEW SEAT MAP <a class="slide-toggle">EXPAND</a></div>
```

Handle the click event of the new `a` and set the text accordingly:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide();

    $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {

         $(this).parent().next(".content").slideToggle(250);

         if($(this).text() == 'EXPAND')
         {
             $(this).text('COLLAPSE');
         }
         else
         {
             $(this).text('EXPAND');
         }
    });
 });
```

NOTE: I've kept this very simple for you and just incorporated the changes into what you already have. There may be better overall approaches and little bits of syntactic sugar (shorthand `if` statements, for example) but I've kept it simple for now.

Comment: Hi Sir DeeMac, I have replaced all corresponding code with your suggested answer and the image is not expanding any more.

Comment: Still has not taken effect Sir, refreshed my HTML page several times.

Comment: I have changed to `$(this).parent()` and `<a href="javascript:void(0)>` and the sliding is back. However, the text is not changing and says `EXPAND` all the time. Assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how I went about the final output with the help of DeeMac's answer (which was Marked as Accepted).

**JavaScript: (`expand-collapse.js`)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide();

    $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".content").slideToggle(250);
        $(this).text() == 'EXPAND' ? $(this).text('COLLAPSE') : $(this).text('EXPAND');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <style>
        .slide-toggle {
            color: blue;
            cursor: pointer;            
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/expand-collapse.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <strong>VIEW SEAT MAP (<span class="slide-toggle">EXPAND</span>)</strong>
    <img class="content" src="images/seatmap.png" width="500" height="300" alt="seatmap">
</body>
```